# How to align a designated initializer in C99 with clang-format?

Tags: clang-format

I am using clang-format 4.0.0 to align a personal project of mine.
I am using the following configurations for clang-format.

```
Language:        Cpp
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
ColumnLimit:     120
TabWidth:        4
IndentWidth:     4
UseTab:          ForContinuationAndIndentation
```

The sample code below is aligned using the above configuration.

```
struct test
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

struct test T = {
    .a = 1, .b = 2, .c = 3,
};
```

Is there any way to align the initialization part like the one shown below.
Basically I am looking for a way to place all the initializers in separate lines.

```
struct test T =
{
    .a = 1,
    .b = 2,
    .c = 3,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using clang-format 6.0.0, the formatting is what you ask for. In fact, there no longer seems to be any way to get the single-line formatting that you don't like.

Comment: It seems to be back in clang 10 ... :(

Comment: Hm. Using https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/, I don't see it on any version of clang-format after 4.0.1.

Comment: I missed the trailing comma after the final struct entry. It seems like that's necessary to break each struct entry on a line by itself...